# Initials of a name

Tags: java, string

I want to show my initials in a code. For example, if my name is `Donald Trump`, the program shall write `D.T`.

How do I do this the easiest way?

```
package pack_prov;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Filip_Degeryd_uppgift_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String f;
        String e;

        f = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("first name ");            
        e = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("last name ");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "initials " + f + e + "is" +
                                           f.charAt(0) + ".") + e.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can e.g. use String#split or String#charAt method and a `StringBuilder`

Comment: can you give an example, i am really new to programming

Comment: @JackFlamp `String.split()` is totally useless for this task. `charAt` is what you need or maybe `subString`, but tat is overkill for this

Comment: You should check your parentheses, as it is your code shouldn't compile or at least it won't do what you expect. Also " i am really new to programming " - you should get the basics then first, _before_ diving into GUI territory.

Comment: replace your last line with this `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "initials " + f + " " + e + " is " + f.charAt(0) + "." + " " + e.charAt(0));`

Comment: If you are new to programing then please read some tutorials first, [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/java-swing-application-example/) is one for swing application. Your code will not even compile and has too many flaws to cover in one question only. As for your specific question about the initials you are already using the correct method [charAt(index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) of the String class.

Comment: ty all for helping

Comment: @XtremeBaumer you are right, I meant subString. monday morning..

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter First Name:");
        String frstNme = scn.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Last Name:");
        String lstNme = scn.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Your Name Initial Is: " + frstNme.substring(0, 1) + "." + lstNme.substring(0, 1) + ".");

        scn.close();

    }

}
```